# How to deal with the third party component dependencies conflict with react native or other component?

Tags: android, components, react-native, android-components

Now I am writing a android app with **react native 0.13.2**, and I want to use some third party components. but those components might be developed base on react native 0.16.0 or other version of react native. For example:
My android app is based on **react native 0.13.2**
component1 is based on **react native 0.14.0**
component2 is based on **react native 0.12.0**
component3 is based on **react native 0.16.0**

As I tested,the react native is not downward compatibility.
what should I do to avoid version conflict? or is there a better way to fixed conflict?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to deal with things the manual way. Upgrade your project, create forks of the components, and update them all to the same base version. You can either update them all to the newest version of React Native, or just pick the newest version among the set of your app and all the components.

From my experience, since most components are on the smaller side they're easy to upgrade to the newest libraries. Most of the things all you have to do is update the package file and maybe change one or two things to go from an old name to a new name. But if you're trying to make anything go past a major version (e.g. when new Android specific APIs come out) it's going to be harder.